# Keep Chrome Shortcut running in Windows Background

Tags: windows, google-chrome

I' building a webapp that reads the database based on time to check changes. When there is a change, a notification in windows displays so the user is notified.
`Chrome-> Dots menu-> More settings->  Create shortcut (as window)` *(Roghly Translated)*

The problem is that the user needs to have the webapp opened so it is working and doing the  before mentioned task. I thought a solution could be to run the shorcut on startup as a service or something (maybe in the icons next to the taskbar clock). But I don't know if this is the best approach or how to do that.

That's why I'm asking for help to find the best approach and if it is the one I'm thinking, to know how could I do that.

Comment: Shortcuts only start something, they don't run

Comment: I think it could start with the system easily but it would be great to make it start minimized in the task bar. Is there any option in the shortcut properties to do so?

Comment: Yes there is a setting